# How can I change the orientation of a print?

Tags: java

```
switch (oper){
    case ('A'):
    case ('a'):
        do{
            System.out.print(num%2);
            num=(num/2);
        }while(num>=1);
        break; 
}
```

So I got this code to convert from decimal to binary, it outputs the result in binary but turned around for example, the number 50 is outputed as 010011 instead of 110010, anyone know a way to turn around the print?

Comment: This is not possible. You will need to build the whole result either into a string or some kind of data structure like an array or a list, then print it all at once.

Comment: Store `num%2` in a List instead of printing. Then `Collections.reverse(list);`. Then print. Or just loop from end to start, that way you won't need to reverse collection.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a `StringBuilder` https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse()

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
str.append();
System.out.print(str.reverse().toString());
```

From your code provided:

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

switch (oper){
    case ('A'):
    case ('a'):
        do{
            str.append(num%2);
            num=(num/2);
        }while(num>=1);
        break; 
}

System.out.print(str.reverse().toString());
```

Comment: Or just cat the strings together. Yes, a StringBuilder is more efficient, but s = a + b is much easier.

Comment: @NomadMaker: He uses `StringBuilder` because it provides the `reverse` method which `String` does not.

Comment: @ the hand of NOD That makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "magic switch" that you can just turn on to print backwards. What you can do, however, is to push all the strings you want to print onto a [*stack*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html), and then print them as you pop them.

```
Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();
do{
    stack.push(Integer.toString(num % 2));
    num=(num/2);
}while(num>=1);
while (!stack.empty()) {
    System.out.println(stack.pop());
}
```

This works because a stack is a Last In First Out data structure. What gets pushed *last* gets popped *first*.